# Avoid round number when casting a float to string

Tags: java, android

I need avoid round number when casting a float to string, I need the number is exactly the same.

In this moment if I make this:

```
String value =  String.valueOf(1234567.99);
```

The the value = 1234568.0  ,so I need the value = 1234567.99 after casting.

Comment: I think something else causing the issue. String.valueOf doesn't round it.

Comment: cannot reproduce: String s = String.valueOf(1234567.99); System.out.println(s); prints 1234567.99

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev try `String s = String.valueOf(1234567.99f);` (note the `f` to make it a float, not a double)

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev A fair point.  But if you prefer his note about "float" over his example code, you can reproduce with String.valueOf(1234567.99F)

Comment: String value =  String.valueOf(1234567.99 - 0.5);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1234567.99` can't be exactly represented as a float. The nearest float is actually equal to 1234568.

If you want more precision, you can use a double: `1234567.99d` will do what you expect.

You can run this simple test to check it (it is in Java but easily transposable on android by replacing the `println`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = 1234567.99f;
    double d = 1234567.99d;
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(f));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d));
}
```

prints:

> 1234568
>   1234567.98999999999068677425384521484375

Note: `String.valueOf(double)` does round the double to another representation, with less decimals, of the same double. In other words, as you see above `1234567.99d` can't be represented as a double and the nearest double is `1234567.98999999999068677425384521484375`. But `String.valueOf` figures it out and uses the first representation of that double (with only 2 decimals) since they are effectively the same double according to the specifications of the language.

Comment: yes, supports the double figures larger than a float, it works great precision

Answer (score 1):

`String.valueOf()` never round off any number you have some other issue but you can try it as:

```
String value =  ""+1234567.99;
```

Comment: in your example, the number is a double, not a float.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = Double.toString(1234567.99);
```

**update:** for more control over the string's format, use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html)

For example:

```
java.text.DecimalFormat formater = new java.text.DecimalFormat();
formater.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
formater.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
formater.setGroupingUsed(false);
java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setNaN("NaN");
formater.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
String s = formater.format(1234567.99);
```